# How to pass object to ApiController from Angular Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to pass a object Id to a ApiController. Right now nothing is being passed. There are no errors either. Now when I specifically put a JobId in the Get Call everything works fine so I am stuck on how to make it work with any JobId.

View

```
<div class="inline-fields">
<label>JobId:</label>
<input ng-model="currentItem.JobId" type="text">
 </div>
     <div class="inline-fields">
 <label>JobName:</label>
 <input ng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">
  </div>

 <input ng-click="EmailPdf(currentItem)" type="button" value="Email"  />
```

Controller

```
 $scope.EmailPdf = function () {
   id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/id').success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

ApiController

```
 // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int? id) // allow nullable parameter
    {
        if (!id.HasValue) // if null return an empty string
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // your code :
        JobDataAdapter adapter = new JobDataAdapter();
        Job job = new Job();
        job = adapter.GetJob(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "PdfApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "apiGeneratePdf", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: You are not passing the id to yours ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
   id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

that's one way.  Depending on the complexity of your API you should also look into the [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)  service.

Comment: worked, thanks. I thought about switching to ngResource.

Comment: Yup after you rewrite the same 4 crud operations using $http a few times $resource becomes attractive and IMO worthwhile (also makes it so I am sure to write consistent RESTful bits on the back end).